# How to read Connection String provided in IIS from ASP.NET Core 2.1?

Tags: c#, sql-server, iis, asp.net-core

I'm trying to deploy to IIS on Windows Server 2016. The SQL Server connection string is saved in IIS Connection Strings.

How do I read the connection string from the ASP.NET Core 2 app in startup.cs?

I'm trying to avoid hard coding the string as well avoiding putting it in appsetting.json.

Comment: What do you mean by "IIS Connection Strings." -is this in web.config? The correct place for a connection string in a .net core app **IS** appsettings.json.

Comment: Within IIS Manager, under ASP.NET there is 'Connection Strings' icon. You can add the credentials and connection string for SQL Server.

Comment: Thats not the recommended place to store .net core connection strings - `appsettings.json` is.

Comment: The appsetting.json will be pushed to GitHub with the credentials. It thought that's not best practice.

Comment: You use the environment specific version and ensure that is excluded from your repo https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/aspnet-core-no-more-worries-about-checking-in-secrets/

Answer (score 0):

The ConfigurationManager class enables you to access machine, application, and user configuration information (from = [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager?view=netframework-4.8)).

So, you can read the Server connection strings using:

```
string connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["IISConnection"].ConnectionString;
```